# how to use A-Dir's jest to test B-Dir?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I want to create an auto report system.

The system can `git clone project` and `auto-test` the project.

I run system and the system is in `A path`

I clone a project in `B path` without `npm install` (I don't want waste time)

but I find that when I use

> pathB > pathA/node_modules/.bin/jest

It doesn't work.

and

> pathA > node_modules/.bin/jest

is OK.

BTW, `eslint` is OK

> pathB > pathA/node_modules/.bin/eslint

Comment: I believe a lot of these tools will use relative paths, so they move up the directory tree to pathA for finding code.  Your code is in PathB, so things do not work properly

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my question, use `jest` need require other packages, especially when I jest `react-native` project.

So I have to run `npm install`.